# encrypt form post data before jQuery serialize

Tags: jquery, security, encryption

I am using ajax form submit. Here,  i am using jQuery [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).I like to encrypt(like [md5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)) the data before submitting. How can i do this

my code

```
 var Data = $('#formid').serialize();
    $.post(url,  Data);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Helpful advice.

[MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is not really an encryption, but a one way hashing mechanism.

There is no (reliable) way to decrypt it.

The only real advantage of it is to compare the hash to other data that has been hashed in the same way.

#### MD5 in JavaScript?

There is no way to do it natively, but [functions exist](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/).

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you are looking for SSL technology - in which case it will be seamless.

You don't code it - the browser will handle the encryption by itself.

See http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/144/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis-7/ for how to configure IIS to manage SSL.

Comment: Yup, SSL is by far the best way to secure the transport. Rolling your own encryption is a Bad Idea.